# Pivoting dates in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot

My current data is in the form of:

[image]

How do I transform it into the following:

[image]

Is the following a good way to accomplish this? I have not tried on the original dataset
since there are too many columns, so I want to get the pseudocode correct first.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  
  SELECT 
    date,
    event1,
    event2,
    event3

  FROM dataset
)
PIVOT
(
  
  sum(count) 
 
  FOR event in ('event1', 'event2', 'event3')
)
```

Comment: `SELECT date, event, count FROM dataset`  instread of `SELECT date, event1, event2, .. FROM dataset` will work, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think selecting event1,event2 and event 3 will work because they are not columns, either select data and event or select all.

SELECT * FROM dataset

pivot(sum(count) for event in ('event1', 'event2', 'event3'));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your answer seems correct, consider formatting the SQL code as a code block (e.g. by selecting it and pressing the curly brackets icon in the editor. This improves readability (so does capitalisation of SQL keywords).